# How to improve logging mechanism with Java8s lambdas

Tags: java, logging, lambda, java-8

How is it possible, to improve your logging mechanism, by not having the overhead of string concatenations?

Consider the following example:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LoggerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // get logger
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoggerTest.class.getName());

        // set log level to INFO (so fine will not be logged)
        log.setLevel(Level.INFO);

        // this line won't log anything, but will evaluate the getValue method
        log.fine("Trace value: " + getValue());
    }

    // example method to get a value with a lot of string concatenation
    private static String getValue() {
        String val = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            val += "foo";
        }

        return val;
    }
}
```

The log method `log.fine(...)` will not log anything, because the log level is set to `INFO`. The problem is, that the method `getValue` will be evaluated anyway.

And this is a big performance issue in big applications with a lot of debug statements.

So, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Use [slf4j](http://slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance)?

Comment: Thanks for the information! But, consider if we're saying `log.fine("Trace value: {}", getValue());` it will also evaluate the `getValue` method in any case, won't it?

Comment: yes indeed - I thought you were just concatenating two strings - I had not realised it was 1000 strings!

Comment: Also say use slf4j. For the 99% of logging, it will do with the semantic 'logger.debug("Look at me mom: {}",me)' . But sure, if you know you are going to concat a string a thousand times then wrap it in an if(logger.isDebug()).. . The lambdas is nice but I'm not sure it really adds anything useful and is more efficient.

Comment: Why not just use java.util.logging.Logger.info(Supplier<String>) and be done with it once and for all?

Answer (score 15):

Since Java8 it is possible to use the new introduced [lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) for this scenario.

Here is a modified example of the logging:

**LoggerTest.class**

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LoggerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // get own lambda logger
        LambdaLogger log = new LambdaLogger(LoggerTest.class.getName());

        // set log level to INFO (so fine will not be logged)
        log.setLevel(Level.INFO);

        // this line won't log anything, and will also not evaluate the getValue method!
        log.fine(()-> "Trace value: " + getValue());  // changed to lambda expression
    }

    // example method to get a value with a lot of string concatenation
    private static String getValue() {
        String val = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            val += "foo";
        }

        return val;
    }
}
```

**LambdaLogger.class**

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LambdaLogger extends Logger {
    public LambdaLogger(String name) {
        super(name, null);
    }

    public void fine(Callable<String> message) {
        // log only, if it's loggable
        if (isLoggable(Level.FINE)) {
            try {
                // evaluate here the callable method
                super.fine(message.call());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this modification you can improve the performance of your applications a lot, if you have many log statements, which are only for debugging purposes.

Of course you can use any Logger you want. This is only an example of the `java.util.Logger`.

Comment: Maybe. You may incur a capture cost if you need to pass data from the calling method into `Callable.call`. This might be better than string concatenation but will still likely be more expensive than wrapping the `fine` call in an _if_ statement that checks if the level is enabled. [Goetz discusses capture costs here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_QbkGU_lqY).

Comment: A good starting point for discussion of capture costs in that video (skipping all the nice background info) would be around [36:25][1].

  [1]: http://youtu.be/C_QbkGU_lqY?t=36m25s

Comment: There is no need to extend Logger class and implement custom methods since Java 8 has already logger methods with similar signature: `public void fine(Supplier<String> msgSupplier)`.

Answer (score 11):

@bobbel has explained how to do it.

I'd like to add that while this represents a performance improvement over your original code, the classic way of dealing with this is still faster:

```
if (log.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) {
    log.fine("Trace value: " + getValue());
}
```

and only marginally more verbose / wordy.

The reason it is faster is that the lambda version has the additional runtime overheads of creating the callable instance (capture cost), and an extra level of method calls.

And finally, there is the issue of creating the `LambdaLogger` instances.  @bobbel's code shows this being done using a constructor, but in reality `java.util.logging.Logger` objects need to be created by a factory method to avoid proliferation of objects.  That implies a bunch of extra infrastructure (and code changes) to get this to work with a custom subclass of `Logger`.

Comment: Of course, this is also an option (and perhaps even faster)! **But**, imagine that you have to write this additional `if` for every log statement you have. So, if you don't have a lot of log-statements, this option should be prefered!

Comment: @bobel - Sorry. No I don't prefer it.  I don't accept that it is necessary to "guard" most logging calls, or that you should normally have that many "fine" logging calls in your code in the first place.

Comment: Another point is keeping the levels of the `if` guard and the actual log statement in sync.

Comment: @René - True.  But the two pieces of code are typically on consecutive lines, and the two logging level symbols are in all-caps.  The programmer has to be really careless for them to get out of sync.

Answer (score 10):

Apparently Log4j 2.4 includes support for lambda expressions which are exactly useful for your case (and which other answers have replicated manually):

From https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2015/09/16/a-gentle-introduction-to-the-log4j-api-and-lambda-basics/

```
// Uses Java 8 lambdas to build arguments on demand
logger.debug("I am logging that {} happened.", () -> compute());
```

Comment: Does slf4j have wrapper on this api of  log4j

Answer (score 6):

Just create wrapper methods for your current logger as:

```
public static void info(Logger logger, Supplier<String> message) {
    if (logger.isLoggable(Level.INFO))
    logger.info(message.get());
}
```

and use it:

```
info(log, () -> "x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
```

Reference: JAVA SE 8 for the Really Impatient eBook, pages 48-49.

Comment: In Java 8, java.util.logging.Logger has a Logger.info(Supplier<String>) method, so why write a wrapper when you can use this Logger method directly?

Comment: Because, @KlitosKyriacou, you couldn't change the backing, e.g., to log4j, by simply dropping a JAR in the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

use a format `String`, and an array of `Supplier<String>`. this way no `toString` methods are called unless the the log record is actually publishable. this way you dont have to bother with ugly `if` statements about logging in application code.

Comment: Look at the `getValue()` method. If you put this method as a String argument, it will evaluate in any case. So this is not an effective solution.

Comment: thats fine, im suggesting to change the logger call to `log.fine("%s", this::getValue)`. requires you roll your own logger class.

Comment: Ah okay, I misunderstood your answer. Then that's great! You could extend your answer with this explanation. Now I think about the difference between `Supplier.get()` and `Callable.call()`...

Comment: In my opinion Supplier is better when you have to execute some resource-intensive  operations to recive resultant string.